How to mask the values in query params of URL for Refit API Call in Logs
This is my request :
public class GenerateTokenRequest
{
    [AliasAs("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [AliasAs("secret")]
    public string Secret { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

This is my Refit Interface :
public interface IAuthServiceRefitApi 
{
    [Post("/token")]
    Task<GenerateTokenResponse> GenerateTokenAsync(
        [Query] GenerateTokenRequest command,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

This method gets called and then it creates a URL like this :
https://some-url.com/oauth/token?code=SOME_CODE&secret=SOME_SECRET

I want to mask secret values and code with *** in my logs.
For properties that are part of the body, I have used the PiiString concept and then added a custom delegating handler.
But for properties that become part of the URL as query params, I am unable to do it.
Any suggestions on how I should achieve that?

I assume that your question is not directly related to Refit. To mask some sensitive data in your logs you can use Serilog for logging and its enricher for sensitive data masking. Please refer to this

I am interested in the masking query params that packages only works for body params

Have you had a look at https://github.com/serilog-contrib/Serilog.Enrichers.Sensitive#possible-use-case ?

You have to pass variables directly in method like this:
public interface IAuthServiceRefitApi
{
    [Post("/token")]
    Task<GenerateTokenResponse> GenerateTokenAsync(string code, string secret, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

Using above code, Your URL will be this :
https://some-url.com/oauth/token?code=SOME_CODE&secret=SOME_SECRET


NOTE : As per your existing code, You have to pass JSON body with https://some-url.com/oauth/token URL.


I want to mask those values in URL in my logs

@Hakuna, Remove model GenerateTokenRequest & Directly use variables. Like this :  Task GenerateTokenAsync(string code, string secret, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)

How come that will mask the logs?
